# Scaling an application

Tags: windows, window, display-settings, zoom, winscp

If my question is in any way unclear to you, please read [this link](http://winscp.net/forum/viewtopic.php?p=45454).

I'm wondering if there is a way to set up an application to appear larger.

The reason I'm asking this is that I recently discovered WinSCP and love to use it as an FTP client, but even though it's very useful and practical functionally-wise, I'm having a big problem with its interface. Its text and icons are too small for me to read and use them comfortably. It gives me a headache if I use it for too long.

The application developer could make something, of course, which would be great, but still, what if other applications are made too small (presumably made when screen resolutions were lower) as well, and the developer doesn't do anything?

This could also be useful for visually impaired people (even though there are options to magnify the screen, they might want something more automatic and more specific) or just someone who wants their chat/social networking/etc. application huge so they can read them without their glasses at night. Not to mention games created with a fixed (small) window size such as packed Flash games.

This is a feature made relatively easy on most websites, of course: you just zoom, and unless it's an older site that doesn't have any responsivity, you can use it just fine without difficulty. But with apps, apart from playing with hardly convenient accessibility solutions, I haven't come up with anything.

So here you have it: **Is there a way to make an application window, along with its contents, larger?**

The very ideal way would be to be able to customize it, a bit like you can customize how HTML displays using CSS. But I know that's most probably impossible. Just "zooming" the window, scaling it and its contents proportionally, would do more than fine.

Because honestly, even though WinSCP is the first one that made me react to it, it's not the first time I find an interface tiny.

(In case this is relevant, I use Windows 8 Professional and my resolution is 1920x1080.)
.
.
.

*Lookie, it's even a bit smaller than the Windows Explorer text, which isn't exactly large to begin with.*
(Right click > View Image to see full size.)

[image: Windows Explorer / WinSCP size comparison]

Comment: I suppose so.. but not sure how. In theory. You know the Windows magnifier? Well, if a program hid the window and used similar methods to the magnifier, and mapped the magnified version onto the real one. then that'd do it
also, look up alternatives to windows magnifier

Comment: @Ariane The font size is actually the same between Explorer and WinSCP, except for the tree view in WinSCP which appears to be a slightly different font (which makes it seem about half a pixel smaller).

Comment: What if you use a huge monitor and a low resolution.. i've never tried it but maybe the font is bigger on a bigger screen. Also can you do 1366x768? (maybe not , it's a different ratio) ,  how about anything less than the resolution you have?

Comment: I just googled for magnify whole screen. there's a program called desktop zoom. http://users.telenet.be/littlegems/MySoft/DesktopZoom/Index.html  which apparently is also on magnifiers.org (worth a look there may be other things there too)  Desktopzoom it magnifies the whole screen well and maybe does specific apps too.

Comment: @barlop Yes this sounds nice (although the result from the Windows magnifier is a bit pixellated, so ideally it would be nice if it was smarter and able to re-draw the window with more fidelity) but I don't know if there exists any such thing.

Comment: @DarthAndroid Yes, that's the font I'm talking about (although to be honest I was convinced the rest of the text was a little smaller as well). And how is a different font apparently makes a lot of a difference, because I thought the difference was more than half a pixel.

Comment: @barlop About the low resolution... It WOULD do the job, but it's quite a "violent" solution. I'm not sure I'm not imagining this, but I feel like it reduces the overall quality of display (maybe because it's not the native resolution), and most of all, it's quite inconvenient how it reduces how much stuff I can keep on my start screen. And also, the rest of my computer is quite all right as is. I'd reduce the number of things I can display just because of WinSCP.

Comment: @barlop About DesktopZoom... Apparently, there's a compatibility problem. When I tried to have it zoom my WinSCP window, I got about 50-100 alert popups about an error I wasn't able to read in a very short time, and then the program was stopped by Windows.

Comment: @Ariane  Try "Around Mouse" or "Entire Desktop".  I get popups about a floating point error or something when I try "fixed window". But i'm OK when I try "Around Mouse" or "Entire Desktop".  But I suppose you want the window. Still worth seeing "Around Mouse" option.  magnifiers.org has a forum. You could try a load of the stuff they link to and/or ask in their forum

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9006/discussion-between-barlop-and-ariane)

Answer (score 4):

Try going to the Control Panel -> Display -> Change the size of all items.

That should make your text bigger.

[image: Control Panel, Display]

Comment: I used to have bigger text but some apps displayed funny

Comment: This isn't a bad idea, and compared to a small resolution it doesn't reduce quality (except icons made in a small resolution) and doesn't affect any of the Modern UI, including the Start screen, but I'll agree with @barlop, quite a few things "display funny". Not to mention it feels like overkill a bit, since even things that are large enough already (e.g. task bar and icons) are enlarged, while others aren't (e.g. Firefox UI icons and Adobe CS programs), causing a weird disparity. It causes some issues, e.g. Skype file transfer text slightly hidden, and... Yeah, just "displays funny" overall.

Comment: +1 for the best solution so far, though, even though I won't keep it.

Comment: @Ariane Remember there's also the "Set custom tet size (DPI)" in the left-hand menu. Maybe putting it lower than 125% doesn't cause as many issues.

Comment: @Leathe It remains weird but to a lower extent, while still leaving things a little small. Sadly that option only works well with native Windows things (not even Microsoft-made stuff like Skype).

Answer (score 2):

If you're running windows 7 or better, simply hit <kbd>[image: Win]</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> - this fires windows native magnifier app. You can hit the <kbd>>></kbd> in the magnifying glass to open up the menu and switch it back to the regular size.

This does get a bit pixelly at larger resolutions, so it may not be the best solution, but it dosen't involve third party software or messing with everything to fix one thing.

Comment: That option is sadly probably the worst for my case. It requires an action every time I need to see the window, being a serious annoyance (in that case I much prefer to just get closer to the screen and endure the slight headache) not to mention the Windows magnifier is meant for people with serious sight problems.